# Poner expandablelistview con navigation drawer

Tags: android, eclipse

Bueno

Basicamente mi duda esta explicada en el titulo. He seguido los pasos del siguiente link: [Ejemplo de ExpandableListview](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/)

Y el menu de esta otra: [Ejemplo de Navigation Drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/).

Espero puedan orientarme, ya que soy nuevo en esto de Android. He leido bastantes tutoriales que se acercan algo a lo que deseo pero no logro entenderlo. Estoy usando Eclipse para estos ejemplos, mas adelante cambiare a Android Studio, ahora no.

Gracias por cualquier ayuda.

EDIT

Tengo error en la siguiente linea:

```
listAdapterExpandable = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
```

Con el siguiente error:

"Cannot instantiate the type ExpandableListAdapter"

Comment: En Android Studio lleva un template de Navigation Drawer al crear nueva actividad, ya tienes medio camino recorrido si te decides en usarlo.

Comment: Trata de realizar la implementación y si tienes duda puedes realizar preguntas aquí.

Comment: Si, se que es pedir mucho, colocare el codigo que he logrado hasta ahora. Gracias

Answer (score 9):

#### Como implementar Navigation Drawer con ExpandableListView.

He notado que es algo común esta pregunta, en realidad para agregar un `ExpandableListView` a un `DrawerLayout` es similar a agregar un `ListView`, como puedes notar en este layout `activity_main.xml` :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ffff"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Agregando dentro del `NavigationDrawer` el `ExpandableListView` podemos configurar grupos y a su vez hijos dentro de grupos como se muestra en las imágenes :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta sería la forma de configurarlo desde tu actividad, agrego respectivos comentarios en el código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ExpandableListView expListView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapterExpandable;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // obtiene el DrawerLayout.
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        // obtiene el listview.
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandable_list);
        // prepara datos para Header y Listado en ExpandableListView.
        prepareListData();
        // configura Adapter.
        listAdapterExpandable = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        // configura Adapter en ExpandableListView.
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapterExpandable);
        // Puedes expandir los grupos por default.
        int count = listAdapterExpandable.getGroupCount();
        for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
            expListView.expandGroup(i);


    }


    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Agrega Encabezados.
        listDataHeader.add("Lenguajes de Programación");
        listDataHeader.add("Tipos");
        listDataHeader.add("Paises");

        // Agrega datos.
        List<String> lenguajes = new ArrayList<String>();
        lenguajes.add("C++");
        lenguajes.add("Java");
        lenguajes.add("Ruby");
        lenguajes.add("Python");
        lenguajes.add("Swift");
        lenguajes.add("Objective C");
        lenguajes.add("C#");

        // Agrega datos.
        List<String> tipos = new ArrayList<String>();
        tipos.add("Desarrollo Mobil");
        tipos.add("Escritorio");
        tipos.add("Web");
        tipos.add("Juegos");
        tipos.add("Bases de Datos");
        tipos.add("Analisis de Datos");

        // Agrega datos.
        List<String> paises = new ArrayList<String>();
        paises.add("Rumania");
        paises.add("Ucrania");
        paises.add("México");
        paises.add("Grecia");
        paises.add("Holanda");
        paises.add("El Salvador");
        paises.add("Guatemala");
        paises.add("Canada");
        paises.add("Francia");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), lenguajes);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), tipos);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), paises);
    }

}
```

Vista personalizada para el grupo, `list_group.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#000000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#FF9900" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Vista personalizada para los elementos hijo del grupo, `list_item.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

</LinearLayout>
```

y nuestra clase personalizada `ExpandableListAdapter` que extiende de `BaseExpandableListAdapter` :

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> miListDataHeader; // Titulos en encabezados.
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> miListDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.miListDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this.miListDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this.miListDataChild.get(this.miListDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this.miListDataChild.get(this.miListDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.miListDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.miListDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Si tienes algún comentario sobre la implementación házmelo saber!

Comment: Hola, estoy intentando probar con el codigo que ha puesto @Jorgesys y al igula que a @Kenny, tambien me muestra error en la linea `listAdapterExpandable = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild); ` no se si es por **listDataChild** como se puede corregir.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar el problema de Jorgesys, hay que cambiar el nombre de la clase que pones en la actividad, ya que el nombre por defecto es el nombre de la interfaz, y Android Studio lo confunde, por eso dice que no tiene constructor.