# Alternativas a Sliding Drawer

Tags: java, android

Yo iba a utilizar SlidingDrawer en mi app pero vi que me aparece como obsoleta y que probablemente cause problemas en las proximas versiones de android y quisiera saber cuales son las opciones disponibles en el SDK Android o que librerias de terceros me recomiendan que sean parecidas...

Answer (score 2):

Es obsoleta ya que ahora se tiene [NavigationDrawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Anteriormente se usaba continuamente junto con AndroidSherlock que tambien es obsoleta desde la API 17.

Se recomienda usar [NavigationDrawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) ya que esta contenida en la [libreria de soporte Android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html) por lo tanto puedes cubrir la gran mayoria de APIs anteriores ademas esta optimizada.

Lo mas recomendable es usar el DrawerLayout que contiene el NavigationDrawer, si tratas de usar [SlidingDrawer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) vas a encontrar problemas al implementarla y al final terminarias por reemplazarla.

En este [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6059/95) puedes ver un ejemplo de como agregar un DrawerLayout e incluso agregar un ExpandableListView.