# Android ¿Como implementar un navigation drawer menu en todas las activities?

Tags: java, android, material-design

Buen día.

Tengo listo un **Navigation Drawer**, pero lo que **quiero hacer es que se pueda usar en cualquiera de mis activities.**

¿Como podría implementar esto?.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: ¿Usar en todas las _activities_? Está muy confuso eso, detalla mas tu pregunta porque en lo personal no entiendo a que te refieres, un `Navigation Drawer` es general, es decir, dentro de su menú puedes colocarle los _fragments y activities_ que quieras. Aquí está un [tutorial de Navigation View](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/interfaz-de-usuario-en-android-navigation-drawer-navigationview/)

Comment: Es correcto lo que dices, pero lo que pretendo es que el Navigation Drawer este accesible para cualquier activity en la que me encuentre

Comment: .-. El _Navigation View_  siempre estará accesible por todos lados usando _fragments_ ,  revisa el tutorial que te recomiendo, en caso que quieras usar solo _actividades_, revisa esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities)

Comment: en stackoverflow en español existen varias preguntas/respuestas con esto que requieres. Por ejemplo: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6019/poner-expandablelistview-con-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si deseas implementarlo en varias actividades tendrías que realizar una copia en cada Activity, lo cual no sería buena idea.

Me pongo a pensar como tendrías estructurada tu aplicación, por lo que comentas tienes varias Activity, recuerda que si tienes varias podrías estar realizando un stack de ellas en memoria lo cual puede causar problemas.

Lo correcto es tener una Activity principal que contenga el [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) y dentro podrías realizar una transacción de Fragmentos para agregar el que desees, en lugar de cargar Activities.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de tu Activity realizarías un cambio de contenido de fragmentos vía [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html?hl=id):

```
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();      
  //Se crea una instancia del fragmento a agregar dentro de la Activity.
  Fragment fragment = new myFragment();
  //Se agrega al contenedor.
  fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Para este caso la recomendación es utilizar [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) ya que permiten reutilizar el mismo activity (que incluye el drawer) cambiando el contenido dentro del mismo ciclo de vida de un solo activity, con lo que la lógica del drawer se aplica una sola vez.

[La documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) aclara como implementar el drawer con esta configuración, y si bien es posible es posible hacer un hack usando herencia e includes de vistas para usar activities es fuertemente recomendable que utilices fragmentes como lo indica esta guia.

Answer (score 0):

Una pregunta, ya tengo hecho en navigation drawer (creado como una nueva actividad navigation drawer) y tengo para cada opción un fragment, pero lo que no se es como hacer una ventana inicial, es decir, que sea la que cuando el usuario inicie sesión aparezca y además este también el menú... no se si modificando algún fichero xml que genera el navigation drawer podré usar una como vista principal y los fragments del menu.

Comment: hola @AnnaPS, necesitas algo asi como un login?

Comment: mas o menos lo solucione! no es exactamente un login. Lo que estoy haciendo es un menu lateral y cadaa opción tiene su fragment, pero a la vez uno de esos fragments tiene dentro un buttom navigator view que contiene otros fragments... y es un poco historia la verdad