# Fragmentos con Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android

Como puedo añadir una navigation drawer a un fragmento. 
Necesito poder cargar un meno hamburgesa en un fragmento, el cual pueda a su vez cargar otros fragmentos dependiendo de la selección sin perder el menú de navegación.

he visto que en android studio existe la posibilidad para crear un proyecto que trae por defecto el navigation drawer en un actividad, la diferencia es que necesito cargar el navigation drawer en un fragmento y que este a su vez sea capaz de tener fragmentos anidados.

Comment: Podrías compartir lo que has intentado, el código que has usado y que errores te genera? Puedes mirar el [tour] y [ask] para ver como formular correctamente las preguntas.

Comment: Aquí tienes un tuto..
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Comment: Revisa el tutorial que te proporcionan, como buena practicaregularmente el Navigation Drawer esta en la Activity que contiene el Fragment y no en el Fragment!!! Revisa esa respuesta donde puedes ver la implementación de un Navigation Drawer https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6019/poner-expandablelistview-con-navigation-drawer

Comment: " la diferencia es que necesito cargar el navigation drawer en un fragmento y que este a su vez sea capaz de tener fragmentos anidados." Un fragmento anidado de otro fragmento y me imagino solo en el primer fragmento se vería el Navigation Drawer?

Comment: Correcto solo en el primer fragmento debería cargar Navigation drawable el resto deberían de cargarse sobre el fragmento principal

Comment: Mirate la guia de estilo de Material design, normalmente la apps usan navigation a la actividad y después cargan el fragmento correspondiente, no el revés que puede que en usuabilidad se pierde el foco.