# Menús anidados en Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, menú

estoy creando un menú desplegable en Android Studio (Navigation Drawer), ahora lo que quiero es tener menus y sub-menus, y que los sub-menus esten ocultos y se desplieguen al pulsar sobre el menú que los contiene, no sé si esto se logre en el xml o se logre con sentencias java. Etoy algo enredado con esta pregunta, ojala alguien me pueda ayudar.

Por ejemplo: en el siguiente código tengo tres grupos: quisiera que en pantalla se vean solo los tres menus, luego al pulsar sobre cada uno se desplieguen sus menus anidados.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@mipmap/portal"
        android:title="Portal"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@mipmap/noticias"
        android:title="Noticias" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@mipmap/biblioteca"
        android:title="Biblioteca" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@mipmap/eduvirtual"
        android:title="EduVirtual" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_dir"
        android:icon="@mipmap/directorio"
        android:title="Directorio" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_rutas"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ubicacion"
        android:title="Rutas" />
</group>

<item

    android:title="Plataformas">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_siga"
            android:icon="@mipmap/siga"
            android:title="Siga" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_moodle"
            android:icon="@mipmap/moodle"
            android:title="Moodle" />
    </menu>
</item>

<item android:title="Redes Sociales">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_face"
            android:icon="@mipmap/facebook"
            android:title="Facebook" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_twitter"
            android:icon="@mipmap/twitter"
            android:title="Twitter" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_in"
            android:icon="@mipmap/linkedin"
            android:title="LinkedIn" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_flk"
            android:icon="@mipmap/flickr"
            android:title="Flicker" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gplus"
            android:icon="@mipmap/googlep"
            android:title="Google +" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_inst"
            android:icon="@mipmap/instagram"
            android:title="Instagram" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_round"
            android:icon="@mipmap/tour"
            android:title="Tour 360" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto lo puedes realizar agregando un [ExpandableListview a tu Navigation Drawer.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6019/poner-expandablelistview-con-navigation-drawer)

En un ExpandableListView puedes definir grupos, sub grupos, además definir si estos grupos estan expandidos o colapsados.

[image]

Revisa esta respuesta para implementar un [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) dentro de un [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html?hl=es-419) :

**[Poner expandablelistview con navigation drawer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6019/poner-expandablelistview-con-navigation-drawer)**