# Error con diseño del menu de navigation drawer o alguna alternativa de diseño

Tags: android-studio, xml, android-drawerlayout, androidx

Me encantaría resolver este problema pero después de 3 días de investigación no encontré nada, por lo tanto alguna **alternativa** para diseñar el menú del **navigation drawer** estoy siguiendo [este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGcMLu1GJEc)

Estoy intentando diseñar un navigation drawer al diseñar el menú me sale lo siguiente, por lo tanto la vista no se muestra correctamente.

```
    The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
```

eso me sale al colocar la siguiente linea en el menu

```
tools:showIn="navigation_view"
```

el menú queda de la siguiente manera

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/registr_dolor"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dolor_black_24dp"
        android:title="Registrar dolor" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/registro_cita"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_cita_black_24dp"
        android:title="Registrar cita" />
</group>
<item android:title="sesión">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/salir"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp"
            android:title="Cerrar sesion" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

al migrar el proyecto a androidx el archivo gradle quedo de la siguiente manera.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yordy.richard.ejemplo"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha05'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha03'
}
```

Comment: Para usar `Navigation View` tienes que implentar también esto: `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'` en el gradle del módulo `app`

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya lo he implementado pero sigue sin funcionar, marca lo mismo al igual le hice un rebuild

Comment: ¿Esas son todas tus dependencias? Te falta la de `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`  y quizá alguna más.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si esas son todas mis dependencias, ya modifique la publicación para mostrar todas las dependencias que tengo incluso las que agregue ahorita.

Comment: @RichardYordy comenta que error se muestra ahora que agregaste la dependencia por favor. Debe ser ahora otro el problema.

Comment: @Elenasys sigue mostrando el mismo error al parecer al migrar a androidx no lee las dependencias de support, estoy tratando de adaptar el navigation drawer con forme al link que me proporcionaste

Comment: @RichardYordy agrega el build.gradle que usas, podrías compartir toda la configuración de tu proyecto?,  probablemente  es un problema con AndroidX.

Comment: @Elenasys Ya edite y agregue toda la configuración del archivo gradle de la app.

Answer (score 3):

El error que obtienes:

> The following classes could not be found:
>   - android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

se debe a que es necesario definir la dependencia en tu archivo `/app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

}
```

---

En el sitio puedes encontrar información para crear tu NavigationDrawer:

[Poner expandablelistview con navigation drawer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6019/poner-expandablelistview-con-navigation-drawer/6059#6059)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El ejemplo que me muestras funciona, lamentablemente no ocupo listas expansibles en el navigation drawer, lo intente adaptar a lo que necesito pero no tengo tanta experiencia y no puede lograrlo ya que solo necesito algo parecido a lo que tengo en el menú de ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

El error que te marca es por la dependencia de material design. Yo segui ese mismo tutorial hace tiempo cuando recien iniciaba android.
El problema es la migracion a androidX de tu libreria de material design

intenta cambiar tu linea de

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

por

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Si no te funciona dale clean project, Gradle sync.
Si no te funciona dale del lado derecho hay un pequeño menu que dice gradle, en la opcion que dice app--> build--> clean (doble click) y vuelves a compilar.

Edit: Te comento tambien que Android Studio ya te genera activitys con drawers.
File -> New -> Activity -> Navigation Drawer Activity

Comment: Ya la implemente esa librería me sigue marcando el mismo error, sincronice y todo. Estoy implementando una alternativa para no usar esa linea.. en cuanto la tenga la publicare en caso de no encontrar solución al error.

Answer (score 0):

Yo acabo de migrar un proyecto a AndroidX y tampoco me funcionamaba correctamente. Después de comprobar todo una y otra vez, el problema estaba porque tenía que colocar la etiqueta NavigationView antes de cerrar el layout, es decir:
`...

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background=" #ffffff"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`

en ocasiones, este tipo de cosas se convierten en auténticos quebraderos de cabeza.